# Why does using lstinline inside mathescape inside lstlisting not work?

Tags: listings

I'm trying to typeset some code.  That code has some embedded mathematics, but in the embedded mathematics, I need to reference variables from the code.  I would like for the variables in referenced inside the mathematics to be typeset like the actual code (so I do not want to use the mathtt environment).  Unfortunately I get an error when I try to do this.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
@pre: $ \langle \lstinline!a! \rangle $
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

--- TeX said ---
<recently read> \egroup 

l.6 @pre: $ \langle \lstinline!a!
                                  \rangle $
```

I've also tried using `\lstinline{a}`.  I've also tried embedding this inside an `\mbox` and a `\parbox`.  I've also tried using the `\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=^]` and adding an extra `^` around the math formula.

I cannot simply leave the escape environment as I am wrapping these inlined characters in big symbols like `\left(` and `\right)`.

Comment: Why not simply `$\langle$a$\rangle$`?

Comment: $\langle$a$\rangle$ works in this example, however, $\left($a$\right)$ does not work as mentioned in the last sentence.

Comment: In section 4.14 of the `listings` documentation you find "Don't use any commands of the `listings` package when you have escaped to LaTeX". You can use `$\biggl($` and `$\biggr)$` (or variations thereof).

Comment: I missed that.  Thanks for the citation.  However it doesn't solve the general problem of placing arbitrary formulas that include listings formatted elements within a listing.  The `\savebox` box technique does work, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a savebox.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\boxa
\savebox\boxa{\lstinline{a}}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
@pre: $ \langle \usebox{\boxa} \rangle $
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works!  The syntactic overhead is really high however.  Is there a way to make this more compact?

Comment: @ArlenCox There may be a way to make it more compact, but I'm not sure how to do it, given everything that is going on with `listings`.  I suspect something tricky involving catcodes would be required.  egreg's suggestion is probably best, if you want compact.